# How to change row color background in a ListField after navigation Click?

Tags: blackberry, listfield

I'm beginner in BB dev.  I create a CustomListField and when I click on a row, the background color of this row must change and a new screen must be displayed (it's done!).

Could any one please help me to get this done?
thx

Below is the code:

```
protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time)
       {Field field = this.getLeafFieldWithFocus();

       if(field instanceof ListField)
       {
         // listValues is String[] where you store your list elements.
         // listField is the ListField instance you are using 
           UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new ReadMsgScreen());

           int index= getIndex();
           if(index== this.getSelectedIndex())
           {
               **// I think the  code to change the row's background color must be set here!**

           }

          return true;
        }

       return super.navigationClick(status, time);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

use this it will definately work...

```
int tmpcolor = graphics.getColor();
graphics.setColor(Color.CYAN);
graphics.fillRect(0, y, width, getRowHeight());
graphics.setColor(tmpcolor);
```

thanks...

Answer (score 0):

onerride the paint() method in blackberry as showed the code below..

```
_specialNumbers = new LabelField(Constants.SPECIAL_NUMBERS,LabelField.USE_ALL_WIDTH) {
            protected void paintBackground(Graphics arg0) {
                int color = arg0.getBackgroundColor();
                arg0.setBackgroundColor(Color.LIGHTGREY);
                arg0.clear();
                arg0.setBackgroundColor(color);
            }
        };
```

Comment: I need to call the paint() method for the ListField row.           `int index= getIndex();
           if(index== this.getSelectedIndex())
           {
               **// I think the  code to change the row's background color must be set here!**

           }`

Comment: I tried to override paint() method:                           `TableRowManager ele_row = new TableRowManager()
   {
    protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
     invalidate();
     graphics.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
     super.paint(graphics);
    }
   }; ` but it still not working!! has anyone an idea about how to change the background color of a row in a listfield, please?

Comment: The solution for this issue is to add `g.setBackgroundColor(0x33CCFF);  g.clear();` in the `drawRow(Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height)` method just before `subpaint(g);` This is the hole method: `public void drawRow(Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) { layout(width, height);setPosition(x, y);                         g.pushRegion(getExtent());g.setBackgroundColor(0x33CCFF);g.clear();
                      g.setColor(Color.BLACK);subpaint(g);
                      g.drawLine(0, 0, getPreferredWidth(), 0);g.popContext();}`

Comment: Can please  you specify whether you want to change color on the OnFocus event or you want it to change on onClick event?

Answer (score 0):

In the [drawListRow()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/ListFieldCallback.html#drawListRow%28net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ListField,%20net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) method of the ListFieldCallback for your CustomListField draw that selected line differently and call a [Transition](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11958/Screen_transitions_detailed_overview_806391_11.jsp) to display the other Screen slowly.